# How to color columns in 4/3/4/3 pattern?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Layout of my calendar.]I am trying to color in the columns that correlate to the weekend (Friday through Sunday) on a calendar I've made on my sheet. In essence, the pattern would go something like 4 columns without fill, 3 with fill, 4 without, etc.

I would like to have a more elegant solution than what I have, bc mine (at the moment) is very sluggish and slow.

Note: rng = the range of my calendar

```
For Each col In rng.Columns
    For Each cell In col.Cells
        If k = 5 Or k = 6 Or k = 7 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(210, 210, 210)
        ElseIf k = 8 Then
            k = 1
        End If
    Next cell
    k = k + 1
Next col
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your layout? Might be possible to do with conditional formatting.

Comment: I've added an image for clarification!

Comment: What is shown is what I would like to do, I've just manually colored in those columns at the moment.

Comment: I personally would make row 3 true dates - i.e. 6/1/19, 6/2/19, etc. You can format them as "dd" to keep the appearance the same. Then you can use conditional formatting with the formula `WEEKDAY`.

Comment: Does WEEKDAY include or exclude Fridays?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. That answer works perfectly!

Comment: Oh I guess you should format them as "d" to keep the appearance the same, correction from before :)

Answer (score 0):

A conditional formatting rule based on a formula involving the column index and the MOD function should do nicely.

```
Sub Bands_43()

    With Worksheets("sheet2")

        'reference columns B:Z
        With .Range("B:Z")

            .FormatConditions.Delete

            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ROW(1:1)>3, MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1, 7)>3)")
                .Interior.Color = RGB(210, 210, 210)
            End With

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```